Search engine/tools for math theorems in textbooks
I often find it challenging to search for math theorems that are only available in textbooks, especially when they are slightly more advanced (e.g., Harmonic Analysis). Unlike introductory topics (such as Measure Theory), where a quick search often provides clear sources, these theorems are rarely accessible online unless they're part of lecture notes.

Is there a search engine, method, or tool that allows efficient searching for textbook theorems, particularly when they're stated verbatim across books?"

This is different compared to finding research papers, which is way easier to search for. I'm also affiliated with an institution that allows me to access all that I've ever needed.

You can look into this site https://zbmath.org/
